# Не получается запустить в Main2 код из класса Main

Tags: java, android

ничего  не происходит а должна появится покупка

////

```
public class main

    {
        public Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
        public String mSkuId1 = "dima113xxx.testplaybillinglibrary";
        public String mSkuId2 = "dima113xxx.testplaybillinglibrary_2";
        public  BillingClient mBillingClient;

        public void mBillingClient(final Context context) {
            mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
                    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
                        //сюда мы попадем когда будет осуществлена покупка
                        querySkuDetails();

                        List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                        for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                            String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();
                            if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId1, purchaseId)) {
                                payComplete(null);
                            }

                            if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId2, purchaseId)) {
                                payComplete2(null);
                            }}

                    }

                }
            }).build();
            mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                    if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                        //здесь мы можем запросить информацию о товарах и покупках
                        querySkuDetails();

                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                    //сюда мы попадем если что-то пойдет не так
                }
            });
        }



     public void querySkuDetails() {
            SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
            List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
            skuList.add(mSkuId1);
            skuList.add(mSkuId2);
            skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
            mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                    if (responseCode == 0) {
                        for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                            mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }




        public void payComplete(Context context) {

            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean( "loadUr1" , true);
            editor.apply();
        }

        public void payComplete2(Context context) {

            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean( "loadUr2" , true);
            editor.apply();
        }


       public List<Purchase> queryPurchases() {
            Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
            return purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
        }
    }
```

///

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    }


    public void Start(View view) {
        main a = new   main();
        a.mBillingClient(this);
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(a.mSkuDetailsMap.get(a.mSkuId1))
                .build();
        a.mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }

    public void Start2(View view) {
        main a = new   main();
       a.mBillingClient(this);
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(a.mSkuDetailsMap.get(a.mSkuId2))
                .build();
        a.mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто проходил мимо, у вас название класса с маленькой буквы. Вряд ли это конечно решение проблемы ) но всё же.

Comment: Обязательно следуйте правилам именовая в Java - классы с большой буквы, методы - с маленькой. Без этого код становится нечитаемым для специалистов, у которых годами вырабатывалась привычка читать код. По сути вопроса - наверное у вас не успевает клиент законнектиться. Добавьте логи в каждый метод и смотрите в какой последовательности и что у вас выполняется.

Comment: Также не используйте назначение слушателей кликов из разметки - там много нюансов и вам не нужно пытаться понять когда это работает, а когда нет. В реальном мире так почти никто не делает.

Comment: Также без ваших пояснений что именно не работает - вам сложно помочь. Может у вас падает, может просто ничего не происходит, а может гугл какую ошибку выдаёт. Проблем (не считая именования и форматирования) может быть много. А может, оно у вас даже работает, но вам кажется что нет. Больше деталей в вопрос надо добавить.

Answer (score 0):

Так работать не будет. Сначала нужно дождаться когда наш mBillingClient "соединится" в соотвествущем методе, а потом уже вызывать все остальное. 
Лучше сделать в отдельной активности и внимательно читать [руководство](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview).